# REST to retrieve items in folder and metadata

Tags: 2013, rest, document-set

I'm trying to retrieve all the documents in a document set using REST.

If I use the Lists/GetByTitle(''). I'm able to retrieve an individual item and some associated metadata like so:

```
~site/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('ManagementLibrary')/Items(475)
 ?$select=ID,Title,FLSequence,LSTeaser
```

But I don't see any way to retrieve all the items in a folder/documentset. (My understanding is that docsets are just fancy folders as far as SP is concerned). So in that case I'm following [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#Files) to get all the files in a folder. In this case I'm just trying to get the same resource (item 475 is Interviewing Information) to keep it simple.

```
~site/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/lscsp-cat10/ManagementLibrary/ZCKNDY7XXYKP-15-3/')/Files('Interviewing Information.aspx')
?$select=ID,Title,FLSequence,LSTeaser
```

That does retrieve the correct item, but the only piece of metadata I get is Title. ID and the others (which are user defined) don't show up.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 4):

You might need to take a look at expanding the deferred call for ListItemAllFields. I had a similar situation and my call looked like this

```
site/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/lscsp-cat10/ManagementLibrary/ZCKNDY7XXYKP-15-3/')Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

[Marc D Anderson's Blog - Get all SharePoint Document Library Files and Folders](http://sympmarc.com/2016/04/23/get-all-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-at-a-serverrelativeurl-in-one-rest-call/)

Answer (score 3):

You're retrieving the File Object, which only has 'Properties'. Metadata is defined on the Item.

To view the Properties on that File, try adding '/Properties' to the end of the Query.

To view the Metadata associated with the Item, try adding '/ListItemAllFields' to the end of the Query.

i.e.:

```
~site/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/lscsp-cat10/ManagementLibrary/ZCKNDY7XXYKP-15-3/')/Files('Interviewing Information.aspx')/ListItemAllFields
```